# Find nearest Number when one of the fields is null but you need a Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a report that gives me a Monthly Rate for each Generator we have based on the GenAmps and GenVolts. If My Pricing table has the GenAmps # and GenVolt size then it will populate a Monthly Rate. There are cases as you can see below when there is a GenAmps # and GenVolts value that are not found in my Pricing table. When this occurs i want the MonthlyRate to pull from the closest GenAmps # where the GenVolts value equal, ex(**GenAmps** 15, **GenVolts** KW) which is not found in the pricing table, so i want it to pull the MonthlyRate from the (**GenAmps** 20, **GenVolts** KW)

```
GenAmps GenVolts    PricingGenAmp   PricingGenVolt  MonthRate(160hr)
10       KW           NULL              NULL           NULL
15       KVA          NULL              NULL           NULL
```

This is what my report looks like if they cannot find the GenAmps # and GenVolts value in the pricing table.

```
GenAmps GenVolts    MonthRate(160hr)
  25      KVA         1251
  20      KW          1251
```

(Seen above is from the pricing table). Since these are not in the pricing table i want the 10KW to pull the Monthly rate from the 20 KW and the 15 KVA from the 25 KVA. So it would look like this:

```
GenAmps GenVolts    PricingGenAmp   PricingGenVolt  MonthRate(160hr)
10       KW           20                KW              1251
15       KVA          25                KVA             1251
```

It should look like the data above when the query is working correctly.

There are GenAmps # that range from 10 - 900 that are not found in the pricing table.

this is the Query that i currently have, which needs to be revised so i can make the data look the way i want it to look.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT ContractID, SaleRep, GenAmps, GenVolts, GenPhase, EstRunningHours, MonthlyRate, DeliveryRate, PickupRate, FuelRate, DropCharge, HourlyServiceRate, 
                         CASE WHEN gr.PricingGenAmps IS NULL THEN
                             (SELECT        MAX(GenAmps) AS a1
                               FROM            dbo.GeneratorSizePrices AS a
                               WHERE        (GenAmps < gr.GenAmps) AND a.GenVolts = gr.GenVolts) ELSE gr.PricingGenAmps END AS PricingGenAmp, ISNULL([MonthRate(160hr)],
                             (SELECT        [MonthRate(160hr)]
                               FROM            dbo.GeneratorSizePrices AS b
                               WHERE        (GenAmps =
                                                             (SELECT        MAX(GenAmps) AS a
                                                               FROM            dbo.GeneratorSizePrices
                                                               WHERE        (GenAmps < gr.GenAmps) AND (GenVolts = gr.GenVolts))))) AS Month
FROM            dbo.Elliott_GensRentalRate AS gr
GROUP BY ContractID, SaleRep, GenAmps, GenVolts, GenPhase, EstRunningHours, MonthlyRate, DeliveryRate, PickupRate, FuelRate, DropCharge, HourlyServiceRate, PricingGenAmps, [MonthRate(160hr)]
ORDER BY PricingGenAmps, GenAmps
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: By "...pull from the closest GenAmps # where the GenVolts value equal..." do you mean the next higher GenAmps value found in the table or the GenAmps value having the smallest delta from the not-in-table value? I.e, if the "closest" value in the table is LESS than the not-in-table value, would you use the smaller in-table value?  We really need some more detail, as Sean suggests.

Comment: the latter of the two. Whatever value has the smallest delta from the not-in-table value. So it does not matter if it is less than or greater than the in-table value. @JimtheFrayed

Comment: @ETA did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @scsimon to an extent. i have updated the code, so you can see it. For the month pricing it is telling me it is returning more than 1 value and stops after 324 rows are returned. if you know what is going on that would be very helpful. please review new code seen above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about what's going on in the rest of the query. But the part of the problem that involves matching up a row with the nearest row in another table can be approached this way.

```
select *
from
    dbo.Elliott_GensRentalRate as gr cross apply
    (
        select gsp.*, row_number() over
            (order by abs(gr.GenAmps - gsp.GenAmps), sign(gr.GenAmps - gsp.GenAmps)) as rnk
        from dbo.GeneratorSizePrices as gsp
        where gsp.GenVolts = gr.GenVolts
) as gspr /* GeneratorSizePricesRanked */
where gspr.rnk = 1
```

The `cross apply` lets us look at the value of `GenAmps` from the `gr` table that's outside the query. There are other ways to accomplish this when `cross apply` isn't available but this is very likely to be more efficient. The key then is to rank the potential matches by the absolute value of the differences and then keep only the one that came out on top.

Since you should probably handle ties I used the `sign()` function to determine whether the higher or lower match is the preferred one. As written it would favor rounding up. You could also use `outer apply` if there are cases where a match might not be found at all for some reason.

Comment: what is sgn? is that a function? @shawnt00

Comment: @ETA It should have been `sign()`. It's often `sgn()` on other platforms.

Comment: this was a lot smoother and cleaner. thank you. this simplified the code by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. It's hard to determine without all of the data though. Cheers!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#gens') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #gens
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#genPrice') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #genPrice

CREATE TABLE #gens(
    GenAmps INT,
    GenVolts VARCHAR (3),
    PricingGenAmp INT null,
    PricingGenVolt VARCHAR (3) null,
    MonthRate DECIMAL (6,2) null)

CREATE TABLE #genPrice(
    GenAmps INT,
    GenVolts VARCHAR (3),
    MonthRate DECIMAL (6,2))

INSERT INTO #gens
VALUES(10,'KW',null,null,null),(15,'KVA',null,null,null)

INSERT INTO #genPrice
VALUES(25,'KVA',1251.00),(20,'KW',1151.00)



SELECT
    g.GenAmps,
    g.GenVolts,
    ISNULL(g.PricingGenAmp,(SELECT MIN(gp.GenAmps) FROM #genPrice gp WHERE g.GenVolts = gp.GenVolts and gp.GenAmps > g.GenAmps)) AS PricingGenAmp,
    ISNULL(g.PricingGenVolt,(SELECT GenVolts FROM #genPrice gp2 WHERE gp2.GenAmps = (SELECT MIN(gp.GenAmps) FROM #genPrice gp WHERE g.GenVolts = gp.GenVolts and gp.GenAmps > g.GenAmps))) as PricingGenVolt,
    ISNULL(g.MonthRate,(SELECT MonthRate FROM #genPrice gp3 WHERE gp3.GenAmps = (SELECT MIN(gp.GenAmps) FROM #genPrice gp WHERE g.GenVolts = gp.GenVolts and gp.GenAmps > g.GenAmps))) as MonthRate
FROM
    #gens g
```

Comment: This technique is not good for several reasons. 1) it causes so many joins to `GenPrice` when only one is needed, reducing performance. 2) it's harder to understand because of these extra joins 3) it's too easy to make a mistake and get the join condition wrong. 4) If a duplicate MIN(GenAmps) value did exist (wrong, I know) it would completely break (more of a bad habit of coding style than an issue in THIS query).